# Android: Using multi-dimensional string array for list

Tags: android, multidimensional-array

In my android list page/activity I have a 2 text fields a main and subsection one above each other, but when it coems to creating the array string for it I only see examples with the one section of text.

```
 <resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello!</string>
 </resources>
```

To then create what I want I would do a if statement to match the title then if so add the subtitle, but I would like to have it so I can read my title and subtitle strings something like below:

```
  <resources>
      <string name="hello">
          <item>Hello!</item>
          <item>my subtitle </item>
      </string>
      <string name="hello">
          <item>Hello!</item>
          <item>my subtitle </item>
      </string>
  </resources>
```

But I cannot find an example of how to read this to a list item etc, so I do not need to do a long if statement within my java to match the subtitle to the title.

Many Thanks
Si

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually delimit the text with a pipe | and split it when displaying.  Its a bit ugly, but it works.

```
<item>item1|item2</item>
```

then when I call it in getView(...)

```
String[] r = c.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.arraylist).split("\\|");
```

then I have defines for the index:

```
private final int VIEW_HEADING_TITLE = 0;
private final int VIEW_HEADING_SUB = 1;
```