# How to get the count of array from resources file?

Tags: android, resources, count

I have multiple arrays in resources like this:

```
<resources>
<string-array name="myArray1"> 
    <item>String1</item> 
    <item>String2</item> 
    <item>String3</item> 
</string-array> 

<string-array name="myArray2"> 
    <item>String1</item> 
    <item>String2</item> 
    <item>String3</item> 
</string-array> 

<string-array name="myArray3"> 
    <item>String1</item> 
    <item>String2</item> 
    <item>String3</item> 
</string-array> 
</resources>
```

Now how to get the count of these array dynamically?currently I have 3 arrays.

I can get the particular array items like this

```
String[] resourceString =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
```

But how to get the count?

Comment: I am not sure to understand the question. Do you want to dynamically know the overall number of arrays or do you want to get the array length. In that case use ".length"

Answer (score 9):

```
int length =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML file is not for counting the arrays inside it. It is for storing information that doesn't belong in your code in a **static** way.

This way you can alter menu's, lists **dynamically**.

What you can do is instead of creating multiple arrays, is store it ** multidimensional**. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974165/android-using-multi-dimensional-string-array-for-list)

Now you can count the arrays like **user1969053** is suggesting